# Is there a way to EDIT databases (sqlite) in VSCode?

Tags: python, django, database, visual-studio-code

I am currently trying toed the database that comes with Django. Im tryin to use the VSCode Extension vscode-sqlite to edit the database. While I currently am able to look at the database without the gibberish that shows up when I try to open the database in a text editor, I can't find a way to actually edit the database. I think the buttons on the upper right corner of the UI might have something to do with whatever Im trying to achieve, but I dont really know what they do. Any help would really be appreciated.

[image: the unexplained buttons]

the unexplained buttons

Comment: There is an easy-to-use `sqlite3` command line tool that can edit any sqlite3 database.  https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write data into your database using the Django administrative utility [loaddata command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#loaddata). This utility is often used to initialize a data set after the command has initialized the schema.

You can refer to the [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django#_work-with-data-data-models-and-migrations) of vscode for more details.